# Reading and writing .xlsx files in Matlab 2008 on a computer does not have Microsoft Excel

Tags: matlab, xlsread

I would like to ask a question that is there a possibility to read and write .xlsx files in matlab 2008 on a computer which does not have installed Microsoft Excel. I would like to that is there any openxml kind of solution available for matlab?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at BatchConv, it is based on OpenOffice and should be able to convert the XLSX to CSV or XLS. You can call it via MATLAB `system` command to automate the full process.

Alternatively you can use Apache POI, but if you try to use it keep in mind that your MATLAB 2008 is running an old JRE, it might be incompatible to the latest versions of Apache POI which are able to read xlsx. In case you need to update java to use Apache POI, refer to [this article](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/using-java-7-in-matlab-r2013a-and-earlier)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I do not want to convert to openoffice format. Can is openxml dlls in matlab to load data?

Comment: @User1551892: I don't have any experience using dlls in matlab, but basically you should start here: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/loadlibrary.html